# Trying to import large data from Oracle using a Linked Server on MS SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2005, linked-server

I'm trying to import large amount of data from an Oracle database using a Linked Server on MS SQL 2005.
Here's the OPENQUERY command.

```
SELECT * from OPENQUERY(HRDEV9, 
        'SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
          ,EMPLOYEE_NAME
          ,TO_CHAR(BIRTHDATE,''yyyy-mm-dd'') AS BIRTHDATE
        FROM SYSADM.PS_EMPLOYEES')
```

I have not included all the columns for the sake of keeping my example simple, I have around 180 columns and 75000 rows to import.

This is the error I'm getting when I execute the query:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "HRDEV9" returned
>   message "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.".
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider
>   "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "HRDEV9" reported an error. The
>   provider ran out of memory.
>
> Msg 7372, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 Cannot
>   get properties from OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked
>   server "HRDEV9".

I have enabled autogrowth, and set the unrestricted file growth for both Data and Log files.

I have tried importing only 10 rows with the Oracle ROWNUM but still getting the same error.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: 1. Can you load from another OLEDB? (even SQL Server) 2. Can you query ORACLE database through this driver?

Comment: @vav 1. The data I want to import is sitting on an Oracle database, and the only way I can connect to Oracle is through the linked server using the OraOLEDB.Oracle provider.
2. Yes I can

Answer (score 0):

Try importing data from Oracle into CSV and then load it into MS SQL.
Sorry for pointing you to my blog, but [here is how to get data fast from Oracle.](http://timnanos.com/the-fastest-way-to-export-data-from-oracle-tutorial/)

Comment: My query has to run in a daily batch overnight, I don't want to import it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this to help others with the same issue.

Apparently this is a bug confirmed by Microsoft. The error message occurs if the linked table contains a column of type NUMERIC.
The workaround is to re-create the linked server to use the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC (MSDASQL).

Here are two ways you can work around the behavior:

**Use the ODBC driver for ORACLE that is provided by Microsoft:**

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'ORACLEODBC', @srvproduct = 'MSDASQL', @provider = 'MSDASQL',
 @provstr = 'DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER=MyOracleServer;UID=USERNAME;PWD=Password;'
go

sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'ORACLEODBC', false, NULL, 'USERNAME', 'Password'
```

**-OR-**

**Use the ODBC driver for ORACLE that is provided by ORACLE:**

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'ORACLEODBC', @srvproduct = 'MSDASQL', @provider = 'MSDASQL',
 @provstr = 'DRIVER={ORACLE ODBC DRIVER};SERVER=MyOracleServer;UID=USERNAME;PWD=Password;DBQ=ORACLE805;' 
go

sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'ORACLEODBC', false, NULL, 'USERNAME', 'Password'
```

Hope this helps.